# Eclipse - How to disable the overwriting mode ? (White vertical rectangle)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have accidently enabled the overwriting modus on eclipse and i can't find how to put it off.
It i's quite annoying when tiping my code. 
I only came across some old posts from 2012 but in the meantime eclipse has been changed.

Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

[Here you can see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKe72.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime i have solved the problem.

It was just a 'shift + 0' and it changed the way of tiping.

Comment: Shift+0 is the usual shortcut for the Insert key...

Comment: i never mentioned that i'm one of the few using azerty keyboard and the insert key wasn't working

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have accidentally pressed the Insert button, Press the insert button again on your keyboard.